# cannot connect to server using php

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="user";
$password="debashree";
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
if ($connect->connect_error) {
 die("connection_aborted".$connect->connect_error);
}
echo "connected succesfully";
```

This is the mysql connection php script. It is constantly showing the error of

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7
> connected successfully

I cannot understand please help me?

Comment: a) check [docs of mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) for the right usage of this function b) `$connect` is not an object

Comment: c) "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'" is pretty clear IMO.

Comment: have you tried with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` ? Are you sure of your credentials ? What happen if you try to connect with this username and this password in a terminal ?

Comment: you missed database name parameter in mysqli_connect
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following changes made :

```
<?php
try{
$host="localhost";
$user="user";
$password="debashree";
$databaseName = "myDB";
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password, $databaseName);
if (**mysqli_connect_errno()**)
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
echo "connected succesfully";
}catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also, mysqli_connect requires database as fourth parameter.

mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

Comment: Then you should check if the user has privilege to access the database. If not then you have to grant access in mysql via following command :

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'yourusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';